# GCM Phonegap PHP Push Notification Android

Tags: php, android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing my personal app using Cordova (Phonegap), Google Cloud Messaging and use PHP as my server. I wish to run my notification to many devices but my problem is, I unable to send the notification from my PHP script to the other devices. If I use my own registration id from my own device, and I run my PHP push notification from my terminal, only my device prompted the notification. My question is, if I want to see all the registration ids from `$gcm_header` and be listed at `$registrationIds`, do I need to register to another devices? Because, at this moment, I just run the app only at my own device. Below is my code:

```
<?php
$gcm_header = 'GOOGLE-API';
$registrationIds = array($gcm_header);
//$registrationIds = array('my-regid-from-my-actual-device');

$msg = array('message' => 'Test message',
    'title' => 'Test title',
    'subtitle' => 'test subtitle',
    'tickleText' => 'test tickleText',
    'vibrate' => 1,
    'sound' => 1);

$fields = array('registration_ids' => $registrationIds, 'data' => $msg);

$headers = array('Authorization: key='. $gcm_header, 'Content-Type: application/json');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;?>
```

Comment: I don't get the first part of your question. But anyway, would you please limit this to a single question (the last look ok).

Comment: Ambigious `$registrationIds = array($gcm_header);` it should be array of device ids

Comment: so this mean, if I want to get the array list of another device, I just need to install my app into another devices, is it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a database table that can store the registration id's of all the registered user. Once that is done your server will be able to send the push notifications to all the devices that are registered by there unique registration id's in that table. You can write a `register.php` file that will have the code for registering users and storing them into the DB.

register.php

```
<?php

// response json
$json = array();

/**
 * Registering a user device
 * Store reg id in users table
 */
if (isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["regId"])) {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $gcm_regid = $_POST["regId"]; // GCM Registration ID
    // Store user details in db
    include_once './db_functions.php';
    include_once './GCM.php';

    $db = new DB_Functions();
    $gcm = new GCM();

    $res = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $gcm_regid);

    $registatoin_ids = array($gcm_regid);
    $message = array("product" => "shirt");

    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);

    echo $result;
} else {
    // user details missing
}
?>
```

For more detailed description you can take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/).